# Bash script spawns not child processes of cat

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, cat

I have the simple bash script which just redirects output of sevice to the file:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERIAL_LOCK=/tmp/serial.lock

if [ -f $SERIAL_LOCK ]
    then
    read pid < $SERIAL_LOCK
    echo "kill previous serial logger with pid $pid"
    kill $pid
fi

echo $$ > $SERIAL_LOCK

echo "starting with $$ ..."

cat -s /dev/ttyUSB0 > /serial.log

echo "serial logger $$ stopped"
```

After calling this script more than once `kill` command kills instance of script, but there is `cat` process which is unkilled after every calling this script, like this:

```
 ps aux | grep cat
root      5417  0.0  0.0   4304   304 pts/0    S    09:45   0:00 cat -s /dev/ttyUSB0
root      5425  0.0  0.0   4304   344 pts/0    S    09:45   0:00 cat -s /dev/ttyUSB0
root      5434  0.0  0.0   4304   304 pts/0    S    09:45   0:00 cat -s /dev/ttyUSB0
root      5437  0.0  0.0   4304   336 pts/0    S    09:45   0:00 cat -s /dev/ttyUSB0

 ps aux | grep serial
root      5435  1.2  0.5   5008  2580 pts/0    S    09:45   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/serial_log.sh
```

Why killing script doesn't cause killing of cat process runned by this script and how can I make it works like expected: only one instance f script and cat command are running simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Try killing the script's process group rather than just the lead process. You can do this by sending the signal to a negative process group ID. The process group ID is the process ID of the lead process, so your `kill` just becomes

```
kill -KILL -$pid
```

There is more about `kill` and process group IDs on [the `kill` man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html).